# User prompted to re-authenticate with Google (using OIDC) every time I deploy my app in ECS (using Fargate)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, openid-connect, aws-fargate

I have a .Net 7 web app hosted using AWS ECS Fargate (running on 2 tasks). I use Google as an OIDC provider, and I'm able to succesfully authenticate a user (locally and in production).

I use the following code to achieve this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "AppAuth";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
        options.SlidingExpiration = false;
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = async context =>
            {
                var claimsPrincipal = context.Principal;
                var email = claimsPrincipal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
                
                if (claimsPrincipal != null)
                {
                    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)claimsPrincipal.Identity;
                    if (claimsIdentity != null)
                    {
                        if (!claimsIdentity.HasClaim(x => x.Type == "user-id"))
                        {
                            var response = await api.GetUsersAsync(email: email);
                            claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("user-id", response.Users.Single().UserId.ToString()));
                        }
                        
                    }
                    await context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal, context.Properties);
                }
            }
        };
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com";
        options.ClientId = "***";
        options.ClientSecret = "***";
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.CallbackPath = "/oauth2/idpresponse";
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
            {
                if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri)
                    {
                        Scheme = "https",
                        Port = -1
                    };
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = uriBuilder.ToString();
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };
    });
```

The problem I'm having is that every time I deploy my app using AWS ECS Fargate, and then refresh a page, it redirects me back to the Google login page. For clarity, the process to deploy an app on Fargate involves spinning up two new tasks and then destroying the existing tasks.

One other thing that might be worth mentioning (possibly related), is that I have sticky sessions switched on (required to enable Redis backplane for SignalR to work, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-7.0)).

Another thing that's probably worth mentioning is that I can't replicate this locally; when I restart my app, and then refresh the page, it keeps the signed in experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be because your website's cookie encryption key is being regenerated on every deployment, to a new value. Therefore any cookies left in the browser cannot be decrypted once received by the new deployment, so .NET triggers a new login redirect.

You should be able to verify whether this is happening, by looking at request and response details using your browser tools. If using Chrome, use the [preserve log option](https://blog.logrocket.com/making-the-most-of-the-chrome-developer-tools-part-2-4aa347970b30/) to avoid losing old requests when the Google redirect occurs.

If that does indeed turn out to be the cause,
the resolution is to use one of the [data protection options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview), such as persisting keys to a redis or a database, to ensure that the same key is used when your app is redeployed. Note also that keys are recycled every 90 days by default, which will cause the same cookie rejection event.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct, I'm using redis to persist the keys and the problem goes away. For clarity, this line resolved it:
``builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys");``